# JSON invalid according to jQuery but not JSONlint

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, service, jsonlint

I have a .NET web service returning the following JSON:

```
{"command":"getqcardjson","valuesets":[{"datatable":"eaa65990-8f88-45e0-966b-610858ad4cb6","values":[{"Id":"eaa65990-8f88-45e0-966b-610858ad4cb6","InternalName":"Alpha Profile","TableName":"Alpha Profile","OnMainMenu":"","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"100","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"","IsSchemaObject":"","IsSecured":"False","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"False","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"Information.png","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"980163c2-2688-465d-9383-e5ad4dbf631f","Notes":"This is a test Enquiry profile object called Alpha Profile","Caption":"Alpha Profile","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"2cbc4bc4-7db0-4344-b49a-bbc8ed4e9e60","InternalName":"CompMP","TableName":"CompMP","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"100","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"False","IsSchemaObject":"False","IsSecured":"","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"profile.png","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"980163c2-2688-465d-9383-e5ad4dbf631f","Notes":"","Caption":"CompMP","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"f33038ce-2a64-4e79-99fc-ad6aaf90c2bb","InternalName":"ContactProfile","TableName":"ContactProfile","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"100","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"False","IsSchemaObject":"False","IsSecured":"","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"profile.png","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"980163c2-2688-465d-9383-e5ad4dbf631f","Notes":"","Caption":"ContactProfile","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"fbb39ed3-0409-4712-b6dd-f6853b079aa6","InternalName":"QCardInqMP","TableName":"QCardInqMP","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"100","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"False","IsSchemaObject":"False","IsSecured":"","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"profile.gif","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"980163c2-2688-465d-9383-e5ad4dbf631f","Notes":"","Caption":"QCardInqMP","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"41db39fb-fda8-4c5c-adc4-6e6c1ba77b90","InternalName":"QCEventAttendance","TableName":"QCEventAttendance","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"","IsModelObject":"","IsSchemaObject":"","IsSecured":"","IsFileNewMenu":"","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"","Notes":"","Caption":"Attendance details","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"8f186be5-d0ec-4dc7-bfd5-9b9190644c1f","InternalName":"QCFilms","TableName":"QCFilms","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"","IsSchemaObject":"","IsSecured":"False","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"False","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"2b69073c-4035-4597-acc0-4d8345ba9d1c","Notes":"","Caption":"QCFilms","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"False","IsGeocodable":"False"}]}]}
```

My client code is as follows:

```
$('#panelMiddle').append('Getting Json');
    var url = "svc.asmx/GetJSONData?command=getqcardjson&qcardid=" + QCardId;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#panelMiddle').append('Success');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#panelMiddle').append('Completed');
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#panelMiddle').append(' #ERROR:' + textStatus + '# ' + errorThrown + ' ');
        }

    });
```

If I paste the returned JSON into http://www.jsonlint.com/ then it validates, but the jQuery AJAX call errors with textStatus="parsererror" and errorThrown="Invalid JSON".  My web svc is defined as follows:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] // Required to create web service, even when json decoration present
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] // Required decoration to ensure we can call using json
    public string GetJSONData(string command)
    {
```

Anyone know whats going on?  Thanks.

Firefox console response shows as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://highpersoft.com/">{"command":"getqcardjson","valuesets":[{"datatable":"eaa65990-8f88-45e0-966b-610858ad4cb6","values":[{"Id":"eaa65990-8f88-45e0-966b-610858ad4cb6","InternalName":"Alpha Profile","TableName":"Alpha Profile","OnMainMenu":"","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"100","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"","IsSchemaObject":"","IsSecured":"False","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"False","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"Information.png","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"980163c2-2688-465d-9383-e5ad4dbf631f","Notes":"This is a test Enquiry profile object called Alpha Profile","Caption":"Alpha Profile","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"2cbc4bc4-7db0-4344-b49a-bbc8ed4e9e60","InternalName":"CompMP","TableName":"CompMP","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"100","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"False","IsSchemaObject":"False","IsSecured":"","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"profile.png","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"980163c2-2688-465d-9383-e5ad4dbf631f","Notes":"","Caption":"CompMP","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"f33038ce-2a64-4e79-99fc-ad6aaf90c2bb","InternalName":"ContactProfile","TableName":"ContactProfile","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"100","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"False","IsSchemaObject":"False","IsSecured":"","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"profile.png","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"980163c2-2688-465d-9383-e5ad4dbf631f","Notes":"","Caption":"ContactProfile","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"fbb39ed3-0409-4712-b6dd-f6853b079aa6","InternalName":"QCardInqMP","TableName":"QCardInqMP","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"100","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"False","IsSchemaObject":"False","IsSecured":"","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"profile.gif","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"980163c2-2688-465d-9383-e5ad4dbf631f","Notes":"","Caption":"QCardInqMP","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"41db39fb-fda8-4c5c-adc4-6e6c1ba77b90","InternalName":"QCEventAttendance","TableName":"QCEventAttendance","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"","IsModelObject":"","IsSchemaObject":"","IsSecured":"","IsFileNewMenu":"","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"","Notes":"","Caption":"Attendance details","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"","IsGeocodable":""},{"Id":"8f186be5-d0ec-4dc7-bfd5-9b9190644c1f","InternalName":"QCFilms","TableName":"QCFilms","OnMainMenu":"True","DefaultDataSourceId":"bb4d1622-2e48-40b6-bea7-6355d701445c","DefaultOrder":"","IsChained":"","IncludeInGlobalSearch":"False","IsModelObject":"","IsSchemaObject":"","IsSecured":"False","IsFileNewMenu":"False","IsUpdateShouldRippleCache":"False","AdvancedSearchQueryId":"","CompoundViewQueryId":"","GlobalSearchQueryId":"","Icon":"","DefaultObjectLayoutStyle":"2b69073c-4035-4597-acc0-4d8345ba9d1c","Notes":"","Caption":"QCFilms","IsProfileObject":"True","ShortCacheQueryId":"","WorkflowForCreation":"","IsAllowNewFromExisting":"False","IsGeocodable":"False"}]}]}</string>
```

so presumably that's the problem.  Something wrong with my web method declarations above?

Server now doing this:
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: getqcardjson.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromGetRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, WebServiceMethodData methodData)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}

Comment: Lint finds it okay, but jQuery doesn't? Now that's a rare case. Strange. Are you 10000% sure that the error is related to the JSON you posted and not some other request? Just to make totally sure.

Comment: @pekka in deed :) - is this available online somewhere for easier debugging?

Comment: The JSON data look ok to me. In case you haven't already, use firebug to intercept the response and make sure you are really getting exactly that, no rubbish before or after the json.

Comment: @Pekka - I'm pretty sure, but I'll double check...

Comment: @DEH - That's the *entire* response coming down, not wrapped in anything?

Comment: Well, seems ok to me.  The output that I posted is actually being output by the ajax error function, so presumably that is definitely what it is complaining about.  I'll do firefox intercept...  (Also, sorry, this is all on a local dev box)

Comment: The firefox console shows the response as follows:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you have to set the `contentType` when making a JSON request to an ASP.Net web service, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  //rest of your current options..
});
```

Otherwise that JSON response is wrapped in XML when it comes back.

Comment: Great - that has stopped the error being thrown.  However, none of the ajax callback functions are now running (i.e. the success function isn't running, nor is the complete function.)  So it has fixed the problem, but I'm left with no response at all...

Comment: @DEH -you sure you're not getting a JavaScript error in the console?

Comment: @Nick - I am indeed getting that - I have added the StackTrace to the end of the question...

Comment: @DEH - You should format your parameter as JSON as well, so this: `var url = "svc.asmx/GetJSONData?command=getqcardjson&qcardid=" + QCardId;` should be: `var url = "svc.asmx/GetJSONData";` then you should have `data: '{"command":"getqcardjson"}'` option in `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Ok, sorted.  I changed the url to var url = "hpssvc.asmx/GetJSONData?command=\"getqcardjson\"&qcardid=" + QCardId;
i.e. I enclosed the command in double-quotes.  So, the contentType was the answer, but then I needed to tweak the url to support the new contentType.  Thanks very much everyone!

Comment: @Nick - great - that's a better way of doing it.  Thanks very much again.